# Serilog is printing Both Information and errors with severity level 1 in Azure app insights

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core

I am using Serilog to log into the Azure application insights. For errors/ warnings, it is logging with severity level 1 which is generally information in application insights. Below I have mentioned the required details below.  For error, the severity level should be 3, critical 4, and warning should be 2.For everything it is logging with severity level 1.

App.setting.json

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights", "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning",
        "System": "Error"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithExceptionDetails", "WithCustomContext", "WithEnvironmentUserName", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:G}] [{Level:u3}] *** [{SourceContext}] *** {Message:lj} | {NewLine:1}{Exception:1}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "instrumentationKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          // "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:G}] [{Level:u3}] *** [{SourceContext}] *** {Message:lj} | {Properties}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Serilog;
using ILogger = Serilog.ILogger;

var envrironment = string.Empty;
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker =>
    {
        worker.UseNewtonsoftJson();
           
    }).ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddLocalClients();
              
        services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(Log.Logger);


    }).ConfigureAppConfiguration(configBuilder =>
    {
        configBuilder.AddCustomConfiguration();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddSerilogProvider(hostingContext);
    });
host.Build().Run();
```

LogBuilderExtension.cs

```
internal static class LogBuilderExtension
{
    public static void AddSerilogProvider(this ILoggingBuilder logBuilder, HostBuilderContext hostingContext, Action<LoggerConfiguration>? configureLogger = null)
    {

        var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
            .Enrich.WithProperty("cloud_RoleName", hostingContext.Configuration["WEBSITE_SITE_NAME"])
            .Enrich.WithCustomContext();

        configureLogger?.Invoke(loggerConfiguration);
        var logger = loggerConfiguration.CreateLogger();

        logBuilder.ClearProviders();
        logBuilder.AddSerilog(logger, true);
    }
}
```

[image]

```
public class LoggerExtension : ILogEventEnricher
{
    private const string ClassName = "ClassName";
    private const string MethodName = "MethodName";
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        if (logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue("SourceContext", out var sourceContextProperty))
        {
            var classNameProperty = new LogEventProperty(ClassName, sourceContextProperty);
            logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(classNameProperty);

        }
        if (logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue("AzureFunctions_FunctionName", out var actionNameProperty))
        {
            var methodNameProperty = new LogEventProperty(MethodName, actionNameProperty);
            logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(methodNameProperty);

        }
    }
}

public static class SerilogExtensions
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration WithCustomContext(this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrichmentConfiguration)
    {
        return enrichmentConfiguration.With(new LoggerExtension());
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the framework and version of your App?

Comment: .net core 7, Function apps.

Comment: Function app V4 (out of process).

Comment: Will try to repro from my end and let you know

Comment: Are you looking for the custom properties only? Are you able to log traces if serilog configuration is written in `Program.cs` itself ?

Comment: The requirement is that the application should log the class name and method name as part of custom dimension.